# How can I reset font settings in Edge?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-edge

I downloaded some fonts to my computer but when I opened google search in Edge I saw a very light font:

[image: Google search image]

but when I opened some sites that don't have font displayed in it, they're also like google. I tried to fix this in fonts settings and I messed everything up:

[image: settings capture]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use: Settings -> Reset settings. Use it carefully as all your settings will be reset to default

Or set the custom fonts as seen on the image below:
[image: Edge Customize fonts]

Comment: I cannot find Consolas for the Fixed-width font option.

Comment: @Niing Is it listed on the other options (standard, serif and sans-serif)? I have it as on option on all categories.

Comment: I solved it yesterday but it's a long story. Just gave you an upvote since you trying to help.